# how to make entered text to be one line of text?

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I am trying to make a notification section using table view, view the cell is tapped then it will show the detail of the notification info like this

[image]

as we can see in the first picture (table view cell), the text (the text content, not the title) is clipped. I don't think this is an autolayout issue, since I have set the autolayout constraint like below

[image]

I hope that I can get the table view cell like below, some context will also be displayed in 2 lines in the label.

[image]

I suspect this is because it has entered text

- Dear All,
- (enter)
- Perlu kami informasikan bahwa ..........

maybe thats why i get

> Dear All, **......**

could you please help me ? Thanks in advance

Comment: NumberOflines = 1 ??

Comment: Add label.numberOfLines = 1

Comment: make the number of lines = 1 for the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entered text has embedded newline `\n` characters. That's why you only see the first "line" of the text, followed by the clipping `...`.

To fix that, replace the newline characters with spaces:

```
    // example
    let ls = "This is\nSome text"
    let t = ls.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: " ")
    print("t", t)
    // output is "This is Some text"
```

So, when you want to display the "abbreviated" text, replace the newline chars. When you "expand" the cell, you'll need to show the original string.